# Google Hangouts adapter for Hubot?

Tags: google-hangouts, hubot

I'm currently playing around a bit with Hubot and want to connect it to my and my friends hangout channel. The problem is that I can't seem to find an adapter. There may not exist one (as google hangouts pretty recently remodeled their api) but I wanted to ask you first.

I've found

- A script for launching hangouts, not an adapter: https://www.npmjs.org/package/hubot-google-hangouts
- Old gTalk setups like this one: http://www.mabishu.com/blog/2013/05/11/setting-up-hubot-with-a-gtalk-account-for-fun/
- And nothing more.

TL;DR: Is there an up-to-date Google Hangouts adapter?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update: 2015/01/25

We created an adapter on github which can be found here:

https://github.com/groupby/hubot-hangups

Feel free to add improvements.

---

There is an API here that you could utilize to create a hangouts bot.

https://github.com/tdryer/hangups

And then a bunch of projects that use this service which I haven't looked into.

- HangoutsBot: Python Whistler Bot
- HangupsBot: Bot for Google Hangouts
- QHangups: Alternative client for Google Hangouts written in PyQt
- bastardbot: A bot to follow and interact with Google Hangouts conversations
- pickups: IRC gateway for hangups (prototype)
- telepathy-hangups: Telepathy bindings for Google Chat via hangups library

We'll be releasing a hubot hangouts client at somepoint and I'll create a link here.

Comment: Hope you're well. Is this adapter good to use in its current state? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [hubot-hangupsjs](https://github.com/davidkassa/hubot-hangupsjs).
This basically is the already mentioned [hubot-hangups](https://github.com/groupby/hubot-hangups) adapter in JavaScript/CoffeeScript which are languages that I enjoy way more than python.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following, it's (from what I can tell) the official adapter for Hangouts (now Google Chat).

https://github.com/googleworkspace/hubot-google-hangouts-chat